# wordpress gutenberg: Block validation failed for `core/image` when adding data attribute (data-id="")

Tags: wordpress, custom-data-attribute, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Getting a Gutenberg validation error when adding the **data attribute** (using **Edit as HTML**) to the anchor tag, this issue occurring when**anchor** tag inside **figure** tag.

When user add the image and wrap that image with link, onsubmit event our plugin scan the post content and add the data attribute to link, when refresh/reopen the post edit page again console shows a gutenberg validation error.

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large">
   <a href="http://affiliate.local/wp-admin/post.php?post=56662&amp;action=edit" data-lasso-id="123">
     <img src="http://affiliate.local/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/mint_2018_icon-toolbox-640x640.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-51176"/>
   </a>
</figure>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many try and error I got my solution.

```
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    "blocks.registerBlockType",
    "sample-plugin/plugin/attribute/data",
    (settings, name) => {
        if (name == "core/image") {
            settings.attributes = Object.assign( settings.attributes, {
                'data-id': {
                    attribute: "data-id",
                    selector: "figure > a",
                    source: "attribute",
                    type: "string",
                },
            });
        }
        return settings;
    }
);


function applyExtraClass( extraProps, blockType, attributes ) {
    if(blockType.name != 'core/image') {
        return extraProps;
    }

    try {
        let figure_props = extraProps.children.props;
        let first_child = figure_props.children[0];
        if(figure_props.children && first_child && (first_child.type == 'a')) {
            first_child.props['data-id'] = attributes["data-id"];
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    return extraProps;
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps',
    'sample-plugin/plugin',
    applyExtraClass
);
```

Comment: where do i need to add this snippet?